# Why do I need to click to change focus for element CSS to update

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a checkbox on my page that I've created custom error control CSS attributes for (similar to has-error & has-success):

```
.has-checkbox-error {
    outline-width: 1px;
    outline-style: solid;
    outline-color: #a94442 !important;
}

.has-checkbox-success {
    outline-width: 1px;
    outline-style: solid;
    outline-color: #3c763d !important;
}
```

Here is the HTML for the actual element on the page:

```
        <div class="checkbox" id="div_terms">
            <div id="input_terms">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="terms" name="terms" />
              <p id="terms_p">By checking this box, you agree to the <a id="terms_a" href-"https://www.twfbl.com/joomla30/league-info/league-rules" target="_blank">League Rules</a> and note that they are subject
                to change at any time.  You agree to abide by all league rules.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

When the checkbox value is changed, it runs the following jQuery:

```
jQuery("#terms").on("change", function() {
    if(jQuery("#terms").prop("checked")) {
        jQuery("#terms").removeClass("has-checkbox-success has-checkbox-error has-feedback");
        jQuery("#terms").addClass("has-checkbox-success has-feedback");
        jQuery("#input_terms").prop("title", "");
    } else {
        jQuery("#terms").removeClass("has-checkbox-success has-checkbox-error has-feedback");
        jQuery("#terms").addClass("has-checkbox-error has-feedback");
        jQuery("#input_terms").prop("title", "Required.  You MUST agree to terms in order to join the league.");
    }
})
```

However, when it executes on the page the colorization does not change until you click somewhere else on the page? See https://www.twfbl.com/joomla30/registration-form to see what I mean.

I tried to dynamically change focus in the code (using jQuery["#terms_p"}.focus()), but it did not react the same as clicking on the page.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say the colorization, what do you mean? The red box around the checkbox? That removes for me on your form as soon as I click it. Nothing else changes at all after checking it and clicking away so I assume that is what you mean.

Comment: "change" happens once an element loses focus.  Also, logically changing the value does not trigger a change event.  Only user interactions natively generate events.  If you change the value programatically, you may also have to programatically generate the event as well.

Comment: Yes, the red box.   Once checked, it should change to green.

Comment: @Taplar - I tried using "click" but that was actually changing the checkbox to load already checked (which is not what I wanted).

Comment: Try using the "input" event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
jQuery("#terms").on("change", function() {
    if(jQuery("#terms").prop("checked")) {
        jQuery("#terms").removeClass("has-checkbox-success has-checkbox-error has-feedback");
        jQuery("#terms").addClass("has-checkbox-success has-feedback");
        jQuery("#input_terms").prop("title", "");
    } else {
        jQuery("#terms").removeClass("has-checkbox-success has-checkbox-error has-feedback");
        jQuery("#terms").addClass("has-checkbox-error has-feedback");
        jQuery("#input_terms").prop("title", "Required.  You MUST agree to terms in order to join the league.");
    }
})
```

```css
.has-checkbox-error {
    outline-width: 1px;
    outline-style: solid;
    outline-color: #a94442 !important;
}

.has-checkbox-success {
    outline-width: 1px;
    outline-style: solid;
    outline-color: #3c763d !important;
}

.has-checkbox-success:focus {
    outline-width: 1px;
    outline-style: solid;
    outline-color: #ffcc00 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox" id="div_terms">
            <div id="input_terms">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="terms" name="terms" />
              <p id="terms_p">By checking this box, you agree to the <a id="terms_a" href-"https://www.twfbl.com/joomla30/league-info/league-rules" target="_blank">League Rules</a> and note that they are subject
                to change at any time.  You agree to abide by all league rules.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

You shouldn't focus the checkbox as you can see, if you remove ***.has-checkbox-success:focus*** from the code above, it works fine.

The border of the checkbox in the page you posted is white or maybe set to none, check your css rules.

EDIT:

[troubling css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYfGO.png)

This is the css that's giving you trouble.

Comment: That is odd that it shows as .has-checkbox-success:focus in Google DevTools as the style since the ':focus' is not in the styles.css sheet.   Line 7 is exactly as I typed it above.

Comment: check the EDIT, that css rule overwrite your green border until the checkbox is focused

Comment: Perfect.   I changed the CSS to .has-checkbox-error {
 outline: 1px solid #a94442 !important;
}

.has-checkbox-success {
 outline: 1px solid #3c763d !important;
} and that resolved the issue.   It doesn't explain why the style.css is the last to load and didn't take precedence - but at least it resolves the issue with the !important declaration.  THANKS !!

Comment: that rule overwrite your style.css because of rule itself higher priority